# Could not find `Cargo.toml` running Cargo in docker container

Tags: docker, rust, rust-wasm

I am using the code:

```
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/code \
  --mount type=volume,source="$(basename "$(pwd)")_cache",target=/code/target \
  --mount type=volume,source=registry_cache,target=/usr/local/cargo/registry \
  cosmwasm/rust-optimizer:0.12.4
```

I keep running into this error

> error: could not find `Cargo.toml` in `/code` or any parent directory

Comment: Can you add the command you ran that caused the error to show? What are you trying to achieve? Why are you running this docker container? It's not obvious what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error \`edition2021\` is required when compiling all cw-plus contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72369286/error-edition2021-is-required-when-compiling-all-cw-plus-contracts) (change `0.12.4` -> `0.12.6`)